# Iframe in Internet Explorer Quirks mode will not render at 100% width

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, iframe

I have an iframe which is absolutely poitioned at the top of a page. This is actually a header that is added to customer's webpages, as such DOCTYPEs will vary and thus so will the Document mode.

The iframe renders at 100% no problem in Standards mode, but will NOT in Quirksmode - instead around 90 or 95%, left aligned. Here is the HTML:

```
<iframe 
   src="http://localhost:8080/pagedetails/28/false" 
   id="su3-frame" 
   hspace="0" vspace="0" 
   leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" 
   topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" 
   style="top: 0px;"
   frameborder="0" >
</iframe>
```

and the css:

```
iframe#su3-frame {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border: 0;    
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  z-index: 100000000;
 }
```

Anyone seen this before? Any suggestions for stuff I could try?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this CSS fixes it (in IE8/IE7 Quirks Mode):

```
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
```

It's surely safe to universally include that - I imagine *virtually zero* sites are relying on the `<html>` element having `margin` or `padding`.

Some sites apply a non-zero `margin` or `padding` to `<body>`, but never to `<html>`.

Comment: just posted this too if you have any ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017983/how-to-render-a-div-100-wide-in-internet-explorer-quirksmode